# How does C# disambiguate between multiple interfaces in method calls?

Tags: c#, interface, disambiguation

Assume I have a class `C` that inherits from 2 interfaces (`I1` and `I2`). I also have two versions of a method (`DoStuff`), each taking one of the interfaces as a parameter. If I call `DoStuff(C)`, which one gets called?

```
interface I1 { ... }
interface I2 { ... }
class C : I1, I2 { ... }

int DoStuff(I1 target) { ... }
int DoStuff(I2 target) { ... }

//What gets called here?
C target = new C()
DoStuff(target)
```

If `I2` derives from `I1`, I think it's relatively simple - the `I2` version gets called. I'm interested in the case where the interfaces are independent.

Assume I can't edit `C`, `I1` or `I2`. And .NET 2.0 if that makes any difference.

Comment: A really interesting question!

Comment: -1 You obviously didn't test yourself before asking this question.

Comment: A question about what happens at run time needs to be about code that actually compiles! (and I'm not talking about the ellipses!)

Comment: I find it curious that you decided to post a question instead of just testing it.

Comment: i am not sure will this even compile ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Neither gets called. If your two methods are overloads in the same class, the compiler does not attempt to disambiguate at all. It'll simply not compile your code, saying it's ambiguous between your two overloads as you declared `target` to be a type that implements *both* interfaces.

If you declare `target` to be of one of the interface types, or cast it at call-time (as Jon  shows), then there's no ambiguity.

Comment: +1. I assume that the call to DoStuff is something that you can edit (otherwise it won't compile), so a cast to I1 or I2 will solve your problem.

Answer (score 6):

As BoltClock says, it won't compile. However, it's easy to make it do what you want: just use an expression of the type that you *want* to use for the argument. For example:

```
C target = new C();
DoStuff((I1) target);
```

or

```
C target = new C();
I1 i1 = target;
DoStuff(i1);
```

Basically without any extra work, the *overload resolution* steps will find both methods in the candidate set, and determine that neither is "better" than the other, so overload resolution will fail.

Answer (score 3):

There will be an error when you try to compile it:

> [error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'DoStuff(I1)' and 'DoStuff(I2)'"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky5f1hz8.aspx)